# beginSheet modalForwindow: nil position?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I'm trying to understand how

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

chooses the position on my window since it's modal for no window ? (i passed `nil` to `modalForWindow:)

The first position is the one defined in the Interface builder. Once I closed it for the first time, each time a re-open it, it center in the half top of the screen. Isn't possible to always open it a the same position ?

thx

Comment: Don't use `-beginSheet:…` if you don't actually want a sheet.

Comment: What would you suggest for a modal window then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]` if you simply want to display a modal window.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow: